# stored procedure to return data from multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

`Property` and `Photo`

`Photo` table has `PropertyId` FK column which assigning to Property table.

I have stored procedure which returns data from property table, 
now I want to modify this st. procedure to return photos data 
together with property data in a single st. procedure query. How to do this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllData
AS
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Property
GO
```

Comment: Read on [`JOIN`.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

You join the 2 tables by an Id column.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllData

AS

SELECT * FROM dbo.Property prop
INNER JOIN dbo.Photo photo ON prop.PropertyId = photo.PropertyId
```

[Another post about JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639048/t-sql-select-join-with-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllData
AS
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Photo p inner join dbo.Property pr
on p.PropertyId = pr.PropertyId 
GO
```